# Integral with spectral decomposition

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $A:H\longrightarrow H$ be a self-adjoint operator, where H is an Hilbert space.
Let $(E_{\lambda})_{\lambda}$ be the spectral decomposition of $A$ and $\lambda_0$
a regular value of A with finite multiplicity and isolated in the 
spectrum of $A$. Chosen $\varepsilon$ small enough we have
$$A=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda dE_{\lambda}= \lambda_0\Pi_{\lambda_0}+\int_{|\lambda-\lambda_0|>\varepsilon}\lambda dE_{\lambda}$$.
Why is it that $$(A-z)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\lambda_0-z}\Pi_{\lambda_0}+\int_{|\lambda-\lambda_0|>\varepsilon}\frac{1}{\lambda-z}dE_{\lambda}$$?.
(z is not in the spectrum of A). I know a theorem that states that if $A=\int\lambda dE_{\lambda}$ then $(A-z)^{-1}=\int\frac{1}{\lambda-z}dE_{\lambda}$
but I don't get it in the case above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with finite multiplicity and an isolated point of the spectrum, the **projection-valued measure** $E_\lambda$ on the interval 
$$
I := \{\lambda\in \mathbb R : \vert \lambda - \lambda_0 \vert < \epsilon \}
$$
is **pure point** with just one atom, $\lambda_0$.
For each Borel set $\Omega\subseteq I$, we have 
$$
E_\Omega =
\begin{cases} 
E_{\{\lambda_0\}} & \text{if } \lambda_0\in \Omega \\
0 & \text{if } \lambda_0\notin \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
and therefore if $f$ is a bounded Borel function
$$
\int_I f(\lambda)dE_\lambda = f(\lambda_0)E_{\{\lambda_0\}}
$$
Applying the above equality we can write
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda dE_{\lambda}\\
&= \int_I\lambda dE_{\lambda} + \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus I}\lambda dE_{\lambda}\\
&= \lambda_0 E_{\{\lambda_0\}}+\int_{\mathbb R \setminus I}\lambda dE_{\lambda}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
(A - z)^{-1} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{\lambda-z} dE_{\lambda} \\
&= \int_I\frac{1}{\lambda-z} dE_{\lambda} + \int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus I}\frac{1}{\lambda-z} dE_{\lambda} \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda_0 - z} E_{\{\lambda_0\}}+\int_{\mathbb R \setminus I}\frac{1}{\lambda-z} dE_{\lambda} \\
\end{align}
$$